# Pre-written Cloud Firestore data into plain text in android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a fragment page where users can edit their name and mobile, I wanted the plain text which users can enter data to be pre-written for the second time when they wanted to edit their name, I wanted the name plain text to be pre-written with the data that the user has wrote at the first time

[image]

I am currently using cloud Firestore to store my data, as you can see I have already stored data into the Firestore which is name and mobile, I wanted to pre write the data into the plain text which the user can enter data

[image]

This is the android kotlin source code for the current edit name fragment
[image]

This is the android Kotlin source code for the current edit name fragment
[image]

Comment: Fetch the document from the FIrestore when you come on your edit name and mobile screen and if the record exists, fetch name and mobile and set that data to name and mobile input field. You can find code for that online. Let me know if you face any difficulty.

Comment: @VikasChoudhary binding.edtEditName.text = db.get() 
Am i missing some correct syntax to write this, or actually I have write this wrongly??
the binding.edtEditName is the input text field for the name

Comment: Hi Jian An, welcome to StackOverflow! [Please take note that you should not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Edric Hi, sorry for this as I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the values of "Mobile" and "Name" that corresponds to the authenticated user and populate the EditText objects, please use the following lines of code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid ?: ""
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")
val uidRef = usersRef.document(uid)
uidRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
    if (document != null) {
         binding.edtEditMobile.setText(document.getString("Mobile"))
         binding.edtEditName.setText(document.getString("Name"))
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
    }
}.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
}
```

Comment: Thx for commenting, but im using kotlin language, it seems this is android java??

Comment: Oh, right. My bad, sorry about that. Please check my updated answer using Kotlin. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks, but there is a red line under document.getString(" ") , it says type mismatch, required editable! , and Found: String?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the document to populate the fields, you simply set the text value **AFTER** your get request resolves as it is not instant.

Per the documentation:

```java
db.collection("users")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            if(result != null) {
                binding.edtEditName.setText(result.getString("Name"))
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", exception)
        }
```

Comment: There is a red line under the result?.data.get("username").toString()....
It says that type mismatch, required:editable!, and Found String

Comment: Make sure your binding object is passing it to the correct value, I have no context for what 'edtEditName' is. you may have to set the `.value` instead, but the general idea is there. Adjust accordingly to your app structure